# Semantic-UI: How to handle i18n

Tags: jquery, internationalization, semantic-ui

I have a dropdown that has a property that is language specific (i18n).

My solution at the moment is:

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
        fullTextSearch: true,
        match: "text"
    });

$('.ui.dropdown.de').dropdown({
        fullTextSearch: true,
        match: "text",
        message: {
            noResults: 'Keine Resultate gefunden.'
        }
    });
```

As you can see I have to copy all 'non-i18n' specific properties!

What is the proper way to do this with Semantic-UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement some sort of i18n strategy for all your app. This is not something specific to semantic ui.

One simple way to achieve this is to keep a dictionary with all the sentences and load the needed sentences for the current language.

Example:

```js
const languages = {
  'en-US': {
    'noResults': 'No Results found.',
  },
  'de-DE': {
    'noResults' : 'Keine Resultate gefunden.',
  },
};

const i18n = languages[currentLanguage];

$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
      fullTextSearch: true,
      match: "text",
      message: {
          noResults: i18n[noResults],
      }
  });
```

There are also several libraries to help with this, like http://airbnb.io/polyglot.js/